# if i update table using rowQuery in greendao then after i cant get updated data using below Querybuilder?

Tags: android, greendao

CODE FOR UPDATE DATA IN TABLE

```
        Cursor cursor = daoSession.getDatabase().rawQuery("UPDATE " + PayCycle_tblDao.TABLENAME + " SET " + PayCycle_tblDao.Properties.TotalSaving.columnName + "=" + Utils.getFormatDigit(totalSaving) + " WHERE _id=" + payCycleId, new String[]{});
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        result = cursor.getLong(0);
```

CODE FOR GETTING UPDATED DATA FROM TABLE

```
        payCycle_tblDao = daoSession.getPayCycle_tblDao();
        payCycle_tblQuery = payCycle_tblDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(PayCycle_tblDao.Properties.FromDate).build();
        payCycle_tblList = payCycle_tblQuery.list();
```

Comment: Why you can't get updated data? What is the problem?

Comment: i don't know, where is problem updating data.

Comment: ok, how do you know that something is wrong?

Comment: Ok let me explain,

If i updated table , ok then after call thi below code for getting my updated table data payCycle_tblQuery = payCycle_tblDao.queryBuilder().orderAsc(PayCycle_tblDao.Properties.FromDate).build(); payCycle_tblList = payCycle_tblQuery.list();

but still i got old data payCycle_tblDao not refreshed with updated data

is there any other way to update table record in greendao? then please suggest me...

Thanks,